# 502 Bad gateway error/NameError in Rack application for sinatra app on nginx, passenger in a docker container

Tags: nginx, sinatra, docker, passenger

I am starting with docker (1.3.2) and I am trying to get an example working with nginx, passenger and sinatra. Nginx and passenger seem to work. However, I do not get my sinatra app to run. `curl localhost` gives a *502 bad gateway error* and the same when I try to access in the browser. The question is why that happens and if this is docker related or a configuration issue?

If I place an index.html in public that gets served. If I start the app (see below) with rackup and `curl localhost:9292` I get the expected reply.

The nginx error.log shows:

```
request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "passenger:/tmp/passenger.1.0.766/generation-0/request:", host: "localhost"
App 812 stderr: [ 2015-02-09 16:19:54.3173 828/0x00000000b759a8(Worker 1) utils.rb:84 ]: *** Exception NameError in Rack application object (uninitialized constant Rack::MethodOverride::REQUEST_METHOD) (process 828, thread 0x00000000b759a8(Worker 1)):
App 812 stderr:         from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:14:in `call'
App 812 stderr:         from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:180:in `call'
App 812 stderr:         from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:2014:in `call'
App 812 stderr:         from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1478:in `block in call'
App 812 stderr:         from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1788:in `synchronize'
App 812 stderr:         from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1478:in `call'
App 812 stderr:         from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:74:in `process_request'
App 812 stderr:         from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:141:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
App 812 stderr:         from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:109:in `main_loop'
App 812 stderr:         from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:455:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
2015/02/09 16:19:54 [error] 786#0: *9 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost,
```

Googling for the error message I could not find anything useful. I also tried to set-up the example described here: https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/frameworks/sinatra-framework-and-nginx-on-debian-6-squeeze
with the same results as above.

My directory structure:
    /home/app/sinatra-test/config.ru
    /home/app/sinatra-test/app.rb
    /home/app/sinatra-test/public/
    /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/sinatra-test

config.ru:

```
require 'rubygems'
require './app'
run Sinatra::Application
```

app.rb:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  "Hello from Sinatra!"
end
```

nginx config in sinatra-test:

```
server {
  server_name localhost;
  listen 80;
  root /home/app/sinatra-test/public;

  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_user app;
  passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby2.1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further reading lead to this http://blog.baroquebobcat.com/category/tech/ which pointed to the answer - a mismatch in the rack version installed and the one sinatra requires. I was using the phusion passenger docker image which contained rack 1.6.0. Downgrading to 1.4.0 solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am the Phusion Passenger author. We have recently received a question from another user who experienced this same issue. The cause of the issue is pretty much as ikkjo described it. The solution is to use a Gemfile.

We have documented the issue and its solution on the Passenger Github issue tracker: https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/1478#issuecomment-93730487